# Why python function taking considering last value of keyword argument

Tags: python

```
def foo(x, obj={}):
    obj['x'] = x
    return obj

values = []
for i in range(3):
    obj = foo(i)
    values.append(obj)
values = [v['x'] for v in values]
print(values)
```

In the above snippet code, I am not passing anything to the keyword arguemnt `obj` , so in my understanding it should get initialized with `{}` everytime and the final print statement should print `[0, 1, 2]`.

However in actual, the value being passed is the last value created by `foo` function, i.e. the output I am getting is `[2, 2, 2]`. I can correct this behaviour by passing an empty dict everytime like `foo(i, obj={})` but my question why by default, the `foo` function not initialzing the `obj` with `{}`?

Comment: No, a dictionary is mutable and the basic rule is **never use a default value for a mutable argument**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: The answer in least astonishment thread tagged above is excellent.

Comment: It is clear. Thanks everyone.